# Archive validation error NSSetM

Tags: ios, xcode-organizer

I'm preparing a new version of an app, working in XCode 5. I've built the app, signed it and archived it without any issues and have prepared a new version in iTunes connect. When I validate the archive in Organizer I however get the following error message:

```
**-[__NSSetM addObject:] object cannot be nil
```

I find the error very strange. Why do I get the error when the archive is validated? If there are issues in the code why don't they show up when I build or run the app?

I tried the usual desperate stuff - everything from rebuilding the archive to rebooting the computer.

Any suggestions? Googling didn't give any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs in to the issue, the problem was that there were some empty lines in the info.plist file. The section  with the problem looked something like this

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>80x80</string>
    <string>58x58</string>
    <string>29x29</string>
    <string>120x120</string>
    <string>114x114</string>
    <string>57x57</string>
    <string></string>
    <string></string>
</array>
```

When we removed the empty string values the validation error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have used Mutatble NSSet. And while adding object to it you are adding nil object. Search where you have used NSSet and adding object to it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was very unclear in my question and have edited it