# iOS crash in archives crashes seems block

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, block, archive

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzv2G.jpg]

This crash log is on **AppStore** app analysis，and i get this crash log by the archives in the xcode.

> I tried to fix it, but there msg don't enough or I understand trouble.

i don't understand the crash log，it seems to be block crash but i don't make sure. And it's seems on coreFoundation with `[_NSSetM addobject:]`. i don't know which problem is made crash please help me how can i do with the crash log.

Comment: can you post any specific scenario where exactly its crashing ?

Comment: Im sorry, there crash log in the picture is all

Comment: but how can we identify that where you are getting this crash you have to specify any line of code or something like file detail so we can get idea otherwise we can't help you in this issue.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my project , it caused by below reason :

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>80x80</string>
    <string>58x58</string>
    <string>29x29</string>
    <string>120x120</string>
    <string>114x114</string>
    <string>57x57</string>
    <string></string>
    <string></string>
</array>
```

check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630324/3901620

Comment: add this key or remove this key?  my project dot't include it

Comment: as per depends , if it is require in your project then add otherwise remove that empty key.

Comment: it doesn't require in my project, and it without that empty key. so this crash isn't this problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be below solution could help:

-- Locate your projects `info.plist` file, then find `CFBundleIconFiles` key.

-- ***Remove string with blank values***.

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>80x80</string>
    <string>58x58</string>
    <string>29x29</string>
    <string>120x120</string>
    <string>114x114</string>
    <string>57x57</string>
    <string></string>//remove
    <string></string>//remove
</array>
```

-- `CFBundleIconFiles` value array should not contain any blank string values, now it will be like something below:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>80x80</string>
    <string>58x58</string>
    <string>29x29</string>
    <string>120x120</string>
    <string>114x114</string>
    <string>57x57</string>
</array>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in my project info.plist not find CFBundleIconFiles key

Comment: did you use IAP in your project ?

Comment: not. this is I can get the crash log don't specify. I am very confused